# Async thunk pattern

Tags: javascript

I'm following a lecture by none other than Kyle Simpson himself in which the concept of a synchronous thunk is explained and then an analogous definition of async thunk is given.

The following snippet is provided where the thunk only has one argument (the callback):

```
function addAsync(x, y, cb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        cb(x + y);
    }, 1000);
}

var asyncThunk = function(cb) {
    addAsync(10, 15, cb);
};

asyncThunk(function(sum) {
    console.log(sum);
});
```

My question is why is this preferable over the following code, which actually *is* a thunk with 0 arguments?

```
function addAsync(x, y, cb) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        cb(x + y);
    }, 1000);
}

var asyncThunk = function() {
    addAsync(10, 15, function(sum) {
        console.log(sum);
    });
};

asyncThunk();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the first one because you can control what to do with the result. For example, if I wanted to actually use the result, I would have to copy the second `asyncThunk` so it could do something other than doing `console.log`.